# What payment processing frameworks, like ActiveMerchant, are available for other languages?

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, programming-languages, activemerchant

Rails has frameworks such as [ActiveMerchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/) and [Freemium](http://github.com/cainlevy/freemium/tree/master) (which uses ActiveMerchant) to simplify dealing with payment processing. What other frameworks are there for other programming languages such as PHP or Python?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**  For processing payments, there are several GetPaid modules available for Python.
Check out the [core package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/getpaid.core/0.7.3), as well as [some extensions for different payment methods](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=getpaid&submit=search).

*----------original answer------------*

From a [StackOverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76420/best-php-ruby-python-e-commerce-solution):  [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) is a Python alternative.

See that question link above for other ideas.

Comment: Satchmo is specifically for building a shopping cart whereas I'm interested in just handling payment via a framework, not as a shopping cart.

Comment: got ya, are you familiar with GetPaid at all? See above